# SharePoint 2010 Data view web part filter values show all items when page loads

Tags: data-view-web-part, filter

I prepared the data form web part with data source as SQL table on the page. On the same page, I created another list view webpart which contains items as parameters to filter SQL data through connection web parts. 
I configured the connection between the list view web part and data form web part so that list item values will be passed as filter values to retieve SQL data.

Filtering working fine and when page loads by default first time, the dataview web part is showing data filtered with first item in the list.
I want to show all the SQL data table items at the first time when page loads and users would click filter with their choice to see items.
Appreciate your help.